# The dimension of affine algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am studying Noether normalization, however I found a question about the relationship of the tr.deg and the dimension of affine algebra.
The following are two theorems I read

[image]

Here the theorem claims that any prime ideal chains has a length no more than tr.deg, so I think by choosing the sup of the length of prime chains, I get $\dim R$ no more than tr.deg.

However, in Jacobson’s *Basic Algebra II*, we have a similar theorem

[image]

Here he claims that $\dim R$ bigger than tr.deg.
So what’s the problem? Did I misunderstand? Please help about this and thanks very much.

Comment: Please, if you really must post pictures, ensure they are the right way up.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry about that I did not notice, I have corrected them now.